# Chrome call function in child window doesn't work

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I open a window/tab in Chrome:

```
childWin = window.open('child.html');
```

Then I try to call a function in the child:

```
childWin.objReceiver( {foo: 'blah', zoo: 'bing'} );
```

But I get the following 2 errors in Chrome parent (Firefox works fine):

```
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL file:///C:/Users/Slava/Documents/AMP/app_poc/test/child.html from frame with URL file:///C:/Users/Slava/Documents/AMP/app_poc/test/index.html#. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
Uncaught TypeError: Property 'objReceiver' of object [object Window] is not a function
```

Please advise.

Comment: BTW: Good example of how to ask a question: Concise, shows code, shows the actual error message. And it's *because* you showed the actual error message that I was able to quickly identify the problem. +1, nicely done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When testing this kind of thing, you want to serve the documents from a real web server process (so the URL is `http://...`). The security policy browsers apply to *local* resources (your `file:///...` URLs) can be more restrictive than same-origin policies for a web resource. (Specifically: Some browsers treat local files as not matching *any* origin, even another local file in the same directory.)

Just install a simple web server (or a complex one, if you prefer :-) ) on your machine.

Another thing to be wary of is that you probably can't call a function on the child window **immediately**, because the window may not be loaded yet. So you can watch for `objReceiver` showing up in the child, like so:

```
jQuery(function($) {

  $("#target").click(function() {
    // Open the window
    var wnd = window.open("http://jsbin.com/ofigis/1");

    // Give it a 10th of a second to appear
    display("Window open, waiting for it to appear...");
    setTimeout(watchForWindow, 100);

    // Our function watching for it        
    function watchForWindow() {
      // Is it there?
      if (wnd.objReceiver) {
        // Good, we're done waiting -- send the message
        wnd.objReceiver({
          foo: "blah"
        });

        display("Message sent");
      }
      else {
        // Not there yet, keep waiting...
        setTimeout(watchForWindow, 0);
      }
    }
  });

  function display(msg) {
    $("<p>").html(String(msg)).appendTo(document.body);
  }

});
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/umoyiw/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/umoyiw/1/edit)

*(I'm using jQuery there just for convenience, none of the fundamental bits rely on it)*

Comment: That sucks because I wanted the easy way. Oh well, will do.

Comment: @SBel: It's too bad you're using Windows, because if you were using \*nix I'd say you probably have Python installed, and if you do you can just run this command from a terminal: `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`. That runs a *very, very simple* web server from the current directory. And of course, you can install Python on Windows if you like... Or any of a dozen other tiny web servers.